# How to share Image to multiple social platforms like Instagram in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-networking, socialshare

I want to share data in multiple social platform like Facebook, Twitter, Google+, LinkedIn etc. It works in Instagram application but how can I implement in my iOS application...

Comment: Use relevant SDKs provided by these companies. All of these SDKs are available for iOS.

Comment: use `uiactivityviewcontroller` for your concept

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it will provide sharing service for Facebook and twitter but will G+, LinkedIn and Instagram be available on `UIActivityViewController` by default?

Comment: @NSNoob -- `G+, LinkedIn and Instagram` for these things we need to use SDK or api's else part  `UIActivityViewController` is enough.

Comment: yup that's what I thought. Thats why I recommended using SDKs.

Comment: Thanks you all,
have you any demo source that use that all SDKs that do authenticate only once in app..?

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[_s_image];
    UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]     initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

```
avc.excludedActivityTypes=@[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:avc];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```